# How can I get the indexPath of a UICollectionViewCell and save it

Tags: ios, swift, uicollectionview, uicollectionviewcell

I have a `UICollectionView`, in which are 48 squares. I want that the code knows which `UICollectionViewCell` is selected by the user. After the `UICollectionViewCell` is selected by the user, the user has to press a color, which are in this `VC` as well.

How can I get the cell which is selected?

I did this:

```
func selectedCell (at indexPath: IndexPath) {
    let indexPathForFirstRow = indexPath
    gamePad.selectItem(at: indexPathForFirstRow, animated: false, scrollPosition: UICollectionView.ScrollPosition(rawValue: 0))
}

func collectionView(_ collectionView: UICollectionView, didSelectItemAt indexPath: IndexPath) {
    let cell: UICollectionViewCell = gamePad.cellForItem(at: indexPath)!

    switch cell.backgroundColor {
    case UIColor.lightGray:
        cell.backgroundColor = UIColor.gray
    case UIColor.gray:
        cell.backgroundColor = UIColor.lightGray
    default:
        break
    }
}
```

Comment: Unrelated but consider that the background color is not persistent when the user scrolls and will cause unexpected behavior.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try this code

```
func selectedCell(forCell cell: UITableViewCell) -> IndexPath? {
        let cellPosition: CGPoint = cell.convert(CGPoint.zero, to: self)
        return self.indexPathForRow(at: cellPosition)
    }
```

Comment: That shows two errors: The first in the second line, (can't convert) the other is in the third line (no member indexPathForRow)

Comment: @Just4School  make extension of collectionView and place this function inside the extension and replace (forCell cell: UITableViewCell) by (forCell cell: UICollectionViewCell) and then use it.... it will give you indexPath